# Python urllib (with proxy setting) returns wrong code, Any advice please?

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib, http-status-codes, http-proxy

Using urllib I am checking list of urls where my machine is located behind an squid web proxy, but somehow I can't manage proxy setting correctly in the requests which I am getting 404 instead of 200 when calling the function in a for loop or via a map function.

however single requests work fine!

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool
import urllib.error
import urllib.request

proxy_host = "192.168.1.1:3128"

urls = ['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqZsoesa55w', 
        'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GR2o6k8aPlI', 
        'https://stackoverflow.com/']
```

single request example (works fine):

```py
req = urllib.request.Request(
    url = url[0], 
    data = None, 
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
    })
req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'http')
conn = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

conn.getcode() # --> returns 200
```

This return true http code for single url check.

batch request example (returns wrong http status code):

Function:

```py
def check_url(url):
    req = urllib.request.Request(
        url = url, 
        data = None, 
        headers = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'
        })
    req.set_proxy(proxy_host, 'http')
    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        return  [str(e), url]
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        return  [str(e), url]
    except ValueError as e:
        return  [str(e), url]
    else:
        if conn:
            return conn.getcode()
        else:
            return 'Unknown Status!'
```

```py
for url in urls:
    check_url(url)

# returns: 
>>>404
>>>404
>>>404


p = Pool(processes=20)
p.map(check_url,urls)
#returns: 
>>>[404, 404, 404]
```

Comment: A 404 most likely comes from a web server not the proxy - perhaps YT doesn't like you any more because you've been querying them too quickly? Tried a different set of URLs not on YT?

Comment: Actually, it works fine when proxy not in use. I checked them via python "requests" package with proxy configured, and it works fine again. So I think the problem is not in the destination (e.g. youtube) or in the proxy, but probably in my implementation of urllib.

Comment: Have you tried snooping on the communication python<>server using e.g. telerik fiddler or mitm?